# How can i optimize this regex?

Tags: java, regex

I have this text:

`before label bla bla bla aaaa<TAG1>bbbb bla bla bla bla abcd<TAG2>efgh after`

and this regex:

```
label\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,60}?(?:.){0,}?(\<TAG1\>|\<TAG2\>)(?:.){0,}?\W+(?:\w+\W+){1,60}(?:.){0,}?(\<TAG2\>|\<TAG1\>)(?:.){0,}?
```

It does the job, it works as expected BUT does not really seem optimized.

This is a test: https://regex101.com/r/eS2kS6/1

Basically i have to find a **label** and after N words i should get `<TAG1>` or `<TAG2>` and after N words again i should get `<TAG1>` or `<TAG2>`.

**NOTE:**

It is very important that `<TAG1>` or `<TAG2>` must be seen as a possible "substring" of the word. Sometimes it can be `aaaa<TAG1>bbbb`, sometimes `<TAG1>` directly. As you can see in the example it works in both cases.

Comment: All the 'n words' stuff seems superfluous since you're already matching 'any'  before, between and after the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It often helps to visualize the regular expression:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Note that `(?:.){0,}?` is a roundabout way of saying `.*`. It's also easy to see now that there's two identical blocks which could merged, so lets fix that:

```
label\W+(?:(?:\w+\W+){1,60}?.*(\<TAG1\>|\<TAG2\>).*){2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This is equivalent, but shorter.  From here it becomes a question of what exactly you're trying to match.  All those `\w`s an `\W`s look a little odd to me, especially when used alongside `.`'s. I generally prefer to match `\s` rather than `\W` since I usually really do mean "some sort of whitespace", but you'll need to decide which you actually need.

The "match-one-to-sixty-words-and-not-words-followed-by-anything" pattern you're using (`(?:\w+\W+){1,60}?.*`) is likely not what you want - it would match `a$<TAG` for instance, but not `a<TAG`.  If you want to allow one or more words try `(?:\s*\w+)+`. This matches zero-or-more whitespace, followed by one-or-more characters, one or more times. If you want to limit that to `60` you can replace the final `+` with a `{1,60}` (but it's not clear from your description where the `60` comes from - do you need it?).

So here's where we are now:

```
label\s+(?:(?:\w+\s*)+(\<TAG1\>|\<TAG2\>)\w*){2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This isn't *quite* identical to your previous pattern - it doesn't match `after` in your example string (it's not clear from you description whether it should or not). If you want to keep matching after the second tag, just add a `.*` to the end.

---

All that said, it looks a lot like you're trying to parse a complex grammar (i.e. a [non-regular language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18710751/113632)), and that is [rife with peril](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/113632). If you find yourself writing and rewriting a regular expression to try to make it capture the data you need, you may need to upgrade to a proper contextual parser.

In particular, neither your regular expression nor my tweaks enforce that `N` is the same each time. Your description makes it sound like you only want to match strings where there are `N` words preceeding the first tag, and exactly `N` words in-between it and the second tag.  That sort of match might be possible with regular expressions, but it certainly wouldn't be clean.  If that's a requirement, regular expressions likely aren't the right tool.

Comment: I do not have to parse an HTML document. The <TAG1> and <TAG2> are an example of words i need to check. but it can be replaced with "dog" and "cat" for example. However my goal is a sort of text mining, i have to find specific pattern and extract the content. What is the right tool for you?

Comment: I didn't say you were parsing an HTML document, I said you might be parsing a non-regular language (and HTML is a common example of such a language). A popular grammar generator and parser is [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/), but there are many others.